# Adsense with dynamic content

Tags: adsense, web-crawler, ads

I know that this topic has been discussed before in varying extent but I have some specific queries. I will use an example for this case and would like to request you for your views.

Example:- A home finance management website. There are two pages. The basic page after login is an empty page with a text box. Type in "Rent" and rent details and trends pop up. Type in "Bills" and bill details and history pop up. The data shown to user is different of course.

Now -
1. If I place an Adsense script in the basic home page where I just have a text box, will it be disqualified for not having enough content ?
2. Even if the content changes (AJAX), does the ad change to suit the content ? Does the crawler keep a constant check of index the pages after defined intervals and whatever it finds there is kept and searched for keywords ? The same page may show different content to different users and hence have different keywords. (Also, since login would be cookie based, how does crawler see this page ?)
*Edit -

I know from **[HERE](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html)** that Google does take AJAX calls into account but since the results would be dynamically populated by accessing a database and while populating unique data, the bot looking at the form action page doesn't help much, does it?*
3. Google prefers `GET` method. So if I go like this - `xyz.com?show=rent` / `xyz.com?show=bills`, the page is regenerated and the script reloaded but each time the crawler sniffs any one of the two pages, it might see different content for different users. What does it do ?
4. If I do not reload the page by form submission and the page is not regenerated every time, can I call a function to document.write the div I am putting the ad in ? Would that make it re-sniff the page ?

Any help is much appreciated.